# How to create a variable with other dataset variables as its levels

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataset, where a couple of variables are dichotomised as yes/no.

```
> df[1:20,]
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   black white
   <fct> <fct>
 1 No    Yes  
 2 No    Yes  
 3 No    Yes  
 4 No    Yes  
 5 No    Yes  
 6 No    Yes  
 7 No    Yes  
 8 No    Yes  
 9 No    Yes  
10 No    Yes  
11 No    Yes  
12 No    Yes  
13 No    Yes  
14 No    Yes  
15 No    Yes  
16 Yes   No   
17 No    Yes  
18 No    Yes  
19 No    Yes  
20 Yes   No
```

This creates a lot of variables (my real data has more than one option for race) and doesn’t look very neat as it means a lot of variables unnecessarily.
I want to create a new variable (e.g 'race'), where the now individual variables 'black', 'white' etc are levels to that variable.
Like in this example

```
> df2[1:20,]
# A tibble: 20 × 1
   race 
   <fct>
 1 White
 2 White
 3 White
 4 White
 5 White
 6 White
 7 White
 8 White
 9 White
10 White
11 White
12 White
13 White
14 White
15 White
16 Black
17 White
18 White
19 White
20 Black
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Are there no multiracial people in your data set?

Comment: well, yes there are actually. So one person could belong to more than one race. would you say that creates an issue?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with multiracial cases. @Mael's solution randomly takes one of the races in a multiracial case. Andrea's solution always returns "black" when someone is both black and white. I have posted a solution that hyphenates the races, allowing for multiracial categories

Comment: Yes I't important in my case that people can belong to more than one race. I don't want an individual to be removed from one race category because they also belong to another. I'll check out your solution.

Comment: Hey, what if I have the same situation, but where I want everyone who is both black and white to turn out as white? I know you mentioned one of the solutions here would return all bi-racial individuals as black, but is there a way of deciding what race they should turn out as?

Comment: If you want to do that to just one of the categories, but keep the others multiracial, then add an `ifelse()` to the code I already posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works with multiracial cases.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data with multiracial case
df <- structure(list(respondent = 1:20, asian = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), black = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), white = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  select(asian:white) %>%
  `==`("Yes") %>%
  apply(1, 
        \(.row) colnames(.)[.row] %>%
          str_c(collapse = "-")) 
#>  [1] "white"       "white"       "white"       "white"       "white"      
#>  [6] "white"       "white"       "white"       "white"       "white"      
#> [11] "white"       "white"       "white"       "white"       "white"      
#> [16] "black"       "white"       "white"       "white"       "asian-black"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: maybe a silly question, but if my number of rows are above 100, would I have to add "no"/"yes" manually equal number of times? Such as for 'asian = c("No"...)'.

Comment: you can also use `rep("No", x)` to repeat `"No"` `x` number of times

Comment: Thanks! But I would still have to know exactly which rows that are 'yes' and which rows that are 'no' right? How would you go about that if you have quite a lot of data?

Comment: If you have an existing data set, then you don't need to enter any values manually. The line `df <- structure(...)` is only providing the modified data sample. The code below that is what you want to run on your existing data. You only need to change the `select()` line to correspond to the columns in your data frame

Comment: And if there are no other variables in your data set, like in the sample you provided, then you don't need the `select()` at all

Answer (score 4):

To account for multiple races, use apply on the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), and paste `toString` the column names with `"Yes"`:

```r
df <- structure(list(asian = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), black = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), white = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data.frame(race = apply(df == "Yes", 1, \(x) toString(colnames(df)[which(x)])))

           race
1         white
2         white
3         white
4         white
5         white
6         white
7         white
8         white
9         white
10        white
11        white
12        white
13        white
14        white
15        white
16        black
17        white
18        white
19        white
20 asian, black
```

---

Using `max.col` (works only for one value per individual):

```r
data.frame(race = colnames(df)[max.col(df == "Yes")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` (this assumes that in your dataset a person can only be of 1 race):

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                  black = c("No", "Yes"),
                  white = c("Yes", "No"))

dat |> mutate(
        race = case_when(black == "Yes" ~ "black",
                         white == "Yes" ~ "white")
)
```

Output:

```r
#>   id black white  race
#> 1  1    No   Yes white
#> 2  2   Yes    No black
```